# Where can I find a 130 bcd single speed chainring with 58 or 60 teeth?

Tags: chainring, single-speed

Where can I find a 130 [bcd](http://sheldonbrown.com/gloss_bo-z.html#bcd) single speed chainring with 58 or 60 teeth? I am attempting to setup a goldsprints setup using a very large front ring and a small rear freewheel.

Comment: I bought a 60T chainring for my small wheeled folding bike on eBay. Link will be obsolete, but a search just now found a "Specialized 60 Tooth Chainring 130 BCD Recumbent RARE NOS", and a TA Alize listing with a 60T option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vuelta makes one, and you can [buy it from them directly](http://www.vueltausa.com/se-chain-ring-130mm-38-60t-1.html).  If you prefer to buy locally and immediately, I'd suggest looking for a local shop that specializes in recumbents or trikes.  Vuelta has [a few distributors](http://www.vueltausa.com/international-distributors) 
including KHS, so you should also be able to get many local bicycle shops to special-order you one.

Comment: Fixed broken link to buy the 60t chainring from vuelta. I did aquire 2 of these.

Answer (score 3):

I've been looking for the same thing for a while. Rotor makes a ring that might be of interest: A Q-Ring (oval shape to maximize power stroke) in a 56t in a 130bcd.  That ring goes up to a 59t at the largest point. They say that it is effectively a 58T ring.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check Kraynick's Bike Shop in Pittsburgh, PA, Jerry's telephone number is (412) 621-6160. He probably has one in his multi-story shop or could know where to find one.

Comment: I like your confidence in Jerry. I may stop by his shop and ask around before I order online since I happen to live about 1 mile away.